# Adding dynamic content to Jquery slider

Tags: javascript

I want to add dynamic contents to the slides of my jquery slider. the dynamic contents are selected by user through select boxes. The problem is when I add dynamic content it is shown in the div of slider but as soon as I click on Next or Prev that content is lost:(
Please tell me how to store that information on the slider page, so that it won't get lost.
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I do this sort of thing all the time. Put the slider on a separate page with all its logic (ie reading the the slides etc from a table). Make it entirely self contained. You can either pass some variables from your user selection or set a session variable that controls the dynamic retrieval.

In your main page call this page with JQuery, something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mysliderdiv').load("whateverthepagewiththeslideriscalled");
});
```

You can put logic on the boxes to change the session variables. If you are using php for example in the onclick you could use AJAX to pass the selection to a php template which will change the session variable. It will of course be invisible to the user.

As the slider page is loaded by AJAX every time a page is loaded it will be correct.

Sounds a bit long winded but I have done this many times and it works fine.

Comment: but I have to display that information in the same page so this isn't working. what to do ?

Comment: Well AJAX will pull it into a div on your page, so it will be on the same page.